# HTML editor - A free alternative to DreamWeaver

Tags: html, dreamweaver, wysiwyg

In the past, I used to work with DW4 and liked the way it allows you to visually write HTML pages.

Can anyone suggest a free alternative for Windows?

Comment: I know this is not what you are looking for, but: don't use a WYSISYG editor, write the code yourself. It's much cleaner. Test your sites in real browsers. A WYSIWYG editor does not render equal to any browser. I can recommend Komodo Edit for raw code editing.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using something experimental, why not try a nightly of BlueGriffon?

[www.bluegriffon.org/](http://www.bluegriffon.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio does HTML editing and it's not bad. http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/

Answer (score 0):

Try Bluefish and KompoZer from the World of FOSS..:)

Answer (score -1):

Try this. Was ok for me before a got CS4.

http://www.pagebreeze.com/

Comment: installed this, it's junk. installed some robo shopper crap on my laptop. i removed immediately.